# How to create a database from code-first approach - Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

Looking at example it looks very simple but I am not able to create database using code first approach.

My model class:

```
public class Books
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

`DbContext`:

```
public class BookDBContext : DbContext
{
        public DbSet<Books> Books { get; set; }

        public BookDBContext() : base("name=BookDBContext")
        {
        }
}
```

Controller code:

```
public ViewResult CodeFirst()
{
    BookDBContext context = new BookDBContext();
    List<Books> result = new List<Books>();
    result = context.Books.ToList();
    return View();
}
```

Config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-EF-20150919111248;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-EF-20150919111248.mdf" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="NorthwindEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Controllers.EF.csdl|res://*/Controllers.EF.ssdl|res://*/Controllers.EF.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=Northwind;user id=imad;password=imad123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="DBEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Controllers.DB.csdl|res://*/Controllers.DB.ssdl|res://*/Controllers.DB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=Northwind;user id=imad;password=imad123;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="DBEEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DB.csdl|res://*/Models.DB.ssdl|res://*/Models.DB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=Northwind;user id=imad;password=imad123;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="BookDBContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Sample;User Id=imad;Password=imad123;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Last one is mine.

Debugger comes and goes out of controller. No DB created in ssms no edmx generated. What else I need to do?

**Update**

I had not installed `EF` using `Nuget`. Just referenced `EntityFramework.dll` from other app. But it's working in `Schema First` approach.

Thanks.

Comment: try changing `providerName` to `"System.Data.SqlClient"`, in code-first the providerName is never `System.Data.EntityClient` (unless for code-first from existing database (not sure)). Also be sure to add at least 1 Book to the `Books` set, otherwise no database is actually created.

Comment: @Hopeless you rocks.